# Finding evens in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program that is made of a function that takes in a 2d array, c0unts the evens in the array and returns the amount of evens in that array.  The function isn't returning the value that i intend it to, which is 6.   Sometimes I get 0, sometimes I get a number like 2147483646.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;



const int MaxNumOfRows = 3;
const int MaxNumOfColumns = 2;


int Even(int A[MaxNumOfRows][MaxNumOfColumns], int length, int width)
{

int NumnberOfEvens = 0;
int i;
int j;

for (i = 0; i < length; length++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < width; width++)
    {
        if (A[i][j] % 2 == 0)
        {
            NumnberOfEvens++;
        }
    }
}

return NumnberOfEvens;

}

int main()
{



//int output = 0;
int A[MaxNumOfRows][MaxNumOfColumns] =
{
    {2,2},{2,4},{2,2}
};


Even(A, MaxNumOfRows, MaxNumOfColumns);

//output = Even(A, MaxNumOfRows, MaxNumOfColumns);

cout << Even(A, MaxNumOfRows, MaxNumOfColumns) << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger. I've voted to close this as a typographical error

Answer (score 0):

Check those for loops, I imagine you want to be incrementing the variables ++i and ++j rather than width++ and length++.

With an example this trivial, I imagine stepping through the executing code and finding the problem in a debugger would be pretty straightforward...are you writing this using an IDE with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying increment on loop variables ('i' and 'j') here. 'length' and 'width' are increasing (due to length++, width++) whereas 'i' and 'j' are not. So, loop won't stop and thus the garbage values.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; length++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < width; width++)
    {
        if (A[i][j] % 2 == 0)
        {
            NumnberOfEvens++;
        }
    }
}
```

This must work.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        if (A[i][j] % 2 == 0)
        {
            NumnberOfEvens++;
        }
    }
}
```